# source maps util for es6 + minify

Tags: ecmascript-6, porting, ecmascript-5, source-maps

Is there any way to have source maps directly for ES6 code, which is transpiled?
I.e. I write ES6 code, which is transpiled with e.g. [es6-transpiler](https://github.com/termi/es6-transpiler), then minify & combine ES5s into one file.
But I'd like to have sources in original ES6. Is it possible?

Any transpilers/minifiers and build tool (grunt, gulp) would suffice.

---

I don't agree with "off-topic" decision at all, cause the question was about certain practical problem. Nonetheless, I'd provide an aswer I came across today:

https://github.com/azu/multi-stage-sourcemap